# How to sync thunderbird message tags between different TB clients

Tags: sync, thunderbird, tags

I have TB clients (v17.0.8) accross several machines (work, home,...) and I usually use tags to classify messages. However, TB is not syncing these tags accross the different clients (starring messages works though).
Anybody knows if it is possible to sync tags accross TB clients, even if I need to use an extension it's ok.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually create the same tags on the other clients of Thunderbird to see the tags.

Comment: I don't think manually creating the tags on the other machine is what the OP had in mind when he asked how to sync them.